# exchange API not letting me add attachment to an event using ics file as mime stream

Tags: exchange-server

exchange API not letting me add attachment to an event using ics file as mime stream.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Microsoft support for above query and they told it's not implemented yet to create attachment from ics import.
You can create event using ics file but attachment will not be created.

For exchange API's:
So to create attachment to an event we have to first create event using ics import
and then create attachment to event in different call.

Create events as shown above, to create attachments you can use this API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                       xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
                                       xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                                       xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                          <soap:Header>
                            <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
                            <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
                                            <t:ConnectingSID>
                                                <t:PrimarySmtpAddress>%s</t:PrimarySmtpAddress>
                                            </t:ConnectingSID>
                            </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
                            <t:TimeZoneContext>
                              <t:TimeZoneDefinition Id="Central Standard Time" />
                            </t:TimeZoneContext>
                          </soap:Header>
                          <soap:Body>
                            <m:CreateAttachment>
                              <m:ParentItemId Id="%s" ChangeKey="%s"/>
                              <m:Attachments>
                                <t:FileAttachment>
                                  <t:Name>%s</t:Name>
                                  <t:Content>%s</t:Content>
                                </t:FileAttachment>
                              </m:Attachments>
                            </m:CreateAttachment>
                          </soap:Body>
                        </soap:Envelope>'''%(email_id, item_id, change_key, file_name, attahcment_data)
```

item_id - event id comes in response while creating event
change_key - this also we will receive in create event response

Send this post request to "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"

This will create file attachments only for item attachment i have to try it.